# Android Alarm Clock Class with multiple alarms how to populate imageview for each alarm

Tags: android, imageview, clock, alarm, picker

Any Help with this issue is very much appreciated.

I can set multiple alarms with user choosen sounds and would like to give
 the user the same option of saving different images to ImageView when an
 alarm is triggered. MainActivity follows.

The following is the relevant code the the Alarm Class and full code for
 the Picker Activity is about three quarters the way when scrolling down:

```
Main.Java

public class AlarmDetailsActivity extends Activity {

private AlarmDBHelper dbHelper = new AlarmDBHelper(this);

private AlarmModel alarmDetails;

private TimePicker timePicker;
private EditText edtName;
private CustomSwitch chkWeekly;
private CustomSwitch chkSunday;
private CustomSwitch chkMonday;
private CustomSwitch chkTuesday;
private CustomSwitch chkWednesday;
private CustomSwitch chkThursday;
private CustomSwitch chkFriday;
private CustomSwitch chkSaturday;
private TextView txtToneSelection;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

getActionBar().setTitle("Create New Alarm");
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.alarm_details_time_picker);
edtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.alarm_details_name);
chkWeekly = (CustomSwitch)                          

findViewById(R.id.alarm_details_repeat_weekly);
chkSunday = (CustomSwitch) 
findViewById(R.id.alarm_details_repeat_sunday);
chkMonday = (CustomSwitch) 
findViewById(R.id.alarm_details_repeat_monday);
chkTuesday = (CustomSwitch) 
findViewById(R.id.alarm_details_repeat_tuesday);
chkWednesday = (CustomSwitch) 
findViewById(R.id.alarm_details_repeat_wednesday);
chkThursday = (CustomSwitch)
findViewById(R.id.alarm_details_repeat_thursday);
chkFriday = (CustomSwitch) 
findViewById(R.id.alarm_details_repeat_friday);
chkSaturday = (CustomSwitch) 
findViewById(R.id.alarm_details_repeat_saturday);
txtToneSelection = (TextView)
findViewById(R.id.alarm_label_tone_selection);

long id = getIntent().getExtras().getLong("id");

if (id == -1) {
alarmDetails = new AlarmModel();
} else {
alarmDetails = dbHelper.getAlarm(id);

timePicker.setCurrentMinute(alarmDetails.timeMinute);
timePicker.setCurrentHour(alarmDetails.timeHour);

edtName.setText(alarmDetails.name);

chkWeekly.setChecked(alarmDetails.repeatWeekly);
chkSunday.setChecked(alarmDetails.getRepeatingDay
(AlarmModel.SUNDAY));             
chkMonday.setChecked(alarmDetails.getRepeatingDay
(AlarmModel.MONDAY));
chkTuesday.setChecked(alarmDetails.getRepeatingDay
(AlarmModel.TUESDAY));
chkWednesday.setChecked(alarmDetails.getRepeatingDay
(AlarmModel.WEDNESDAY));
chkThursday.setChecked(alarmDetails.getRepeatingDay
(AlarmModel.THURSDAY));
chkFriday.setChecked(alarmDetails.getRepeatingDay
(AlarmModel.FRDIAY));
chkSaturday.setChecked(alarmDetails.getRepeatingDay
(AlarmModel.SATURDAY));

txtToneSelection.setText(RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this,  

alarmDetails.alarmTone).getTitle(this));
}

final LinearLayout ringToneContainer = (LinearLayout)  

findViewById(R.id.alarm_ringtone_container);
ringToneContainer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
startActivityForResult(intent , 1);
        }
});
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent
data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
switch (requestCode) {
case 1: {
alarmDetails.alarmTone =

data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);


txtToneSelection.setText(RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this,
alarmDetails.alarmTone).getTitle(this));
break;
}
default: {
break;
}
}
}
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.alarm_details, menu);
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

switch (item.getItemId()) {
case android.R.id.home: {
finish();
break;
}
case R.id.action_save_alarm_details: {
updateModelFromLayout();

AlarmManagerHelper.cancelAlarms(this);

if (alarmDetails.id < 0) {
dbHelper.createAlarm(alarmDetails);
} else {
dbHelper.updateAlarm(alarmDetails);
}

AlarmManagerHelper.setAlarms(this);

setResult(RESULT_OK);
finish();
}
}

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void updateModelFromLayout() {      
alarmDetails.timeMinute = timePicker.getCurrentMinute().intValue();
alarmDetails.timeHour = timePicker.getCurrentHour().intValue();
alarmDetails.name = edtName.getText().toString();
alarmDetails.repeatWeekly = chkWeekly.isChecked();  
alarmDetails.setRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.SUNDAY, chkSunday.isChecked()); 
alarmDetails.setRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.MONDAY, chkMonday.isChecked()); 
alarmDetails.setRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.TUESDAY, chkTuesday.isChecked());
alarmDetails.setRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.WEDNESDAY,
chkWednesday.isChecked());  
alarmDetails.setRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.THURSDAY, 
chkThursday.isChecked());
alarmDetails.setRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.FRDIAY, chkFriday.isChecked());
alarmDetails.setRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.SATURDAY,
chkSaturday.isChecked());

alarmDetails.isEnabled = true;
}

}

Main XML


<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:isScrollContainer="true" >

<!--
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".AlarmDetailsActivity" >
-->

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
tools:context=".AlarmDetailsActivity" >

<TimePicker
android:id="@+id/alarm_details_time_picker"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/alarm_details_name"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/alarm_details_time_picker"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:ems="10"
android:hint="@string/details_alarm_name" />

<View
android:id="@+id/divider2"
style="@style/Divider"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/alarm_details_name" />

<com.trigg.alarmclock.CustomSwitch
 android:id="@+id/alarm_details_repeat_weekly"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:layout_below="@+id/divider2"
 android:checked="true"
 android:text="@string/details_repeat_weekly" />

 <View
 android:id="@+id/divider1"
 style="@style/Divider"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_below="@+id/alarm_details_repeat_weekly" />

 com.trigg.alarmclock.CustomSwitch
 android:id="@+id/alarm_details_repeat_sunday"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:layout_below="@+id/divider1"
 android:checked="true"
 android:text="@string/details_sunday" />

 <com.trigg.alarmclock.CustomSwitch
 android:id="@+id/alarm_details_repeat_monday"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_alignRight="@+id/alarm_details_repeat_sunday"
 android:layout_below="@+id/alarm_details_repeat_sunday"
 android:checked="true"
 android:text="@string/details_monday" />

 <com.trigg.alarmclock.CustomSwitch
 android:id="@+id/alarm_details_repeat_tuesday"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_alignRight="@+id/alarm_details_repeat_monday"
 android:layout_below="@+id/alarm_details_repeat_monday"
 android:checked="true"
 android:text="@string/details_tuesday" />

 com.trigg.alarmclock.CustomSwitch
 android:id="@+id/alarm_details_repeat_wednesday"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_alignRight="@+id/alarm_details_repeat_tuesday"
 android:layout_below="@+id/alarm_details_repeat_tuesday"
 android:checked="true"
 android:text="@string/details_wednesday" />

 <com.trigg.alarmclock.CustomSwitch
 android:id="@+id/alarm_details_repeat_thursday"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_alignRight="@+id/alarm_details_repeat_wednesday"
 android:layout_below="@+id/alarm_details_repeat_wednesday"
 android:checked="true"
 android:text="@string/details_thursday" />

 <com.trigg.alarmclock.CustomSwitch
 android:id="@+id/alarm_details_repeat_friday"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_alignRight="@+id/alarm_details_repeat_thursday"
 android:layout_below="@+id/alarm_details_repeat_thursday"
 android:checked="true"
 android:text="@string/details_friday" />

 <com.trigg.alarmclock.CustomSwitch
 android:id="@+id/alarm_details_repeat_saturday"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_alignRight="@+id/alarm_details_repeat_friday"
 android:layout_below="@+id/alarm_details_repeat_friday"
 android:checked="true"
 android:text="@string/details_saturday" />

 <View
 android:id="@+id/divider4"
 style="@style/Divider"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_below="@+id/alarm_details_repeat_saturday" />

 <LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/alarm_ringtone_container"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_below="@+id/divider4"
 android:background="@drawable/view_touch_selector"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/alarm_label_tone"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:text="@string/details_alarm_tone"
 android:textSize="18sp" />

 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/alarm_label_tone_selection"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:text="@string/details_alarm_tone_default"
 android:textSize="14sp" />
 </LinearLayout>

 <View
 android:id="@+id/divider3"
 style="@style/Divider"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_below="@+id/alarm_ringtone_container" />
 </RelativeLayout>

 </ScrollView>

 My problem and question is here with the ImagePicker activity and
 the setting of the image to ImageView.I can pick and set it to the
 ImageView,but have no clue on how to make it stay when the activity 
 is closed or destroyed. I need the same functionality for each 
 alarm as they will have different images in ImageView. I was
 thinking maybe use Preferences to keep track or use item position as
 way to keep track instead of file name.

 The following is what I have for the image picker activity:

 Main.Java


 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 private Uri mImageCaptureUri;
 private ImageView mImageView;  

 private static final int PICK_FROM_CAMERA = 1;
 private static final int PICK_FROM_FILE = 2;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 setContentView(R.layout.main);

 final String [] items          = new String [] {"From Camera", "From SD
 Card"};                
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter   = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,
 android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,items);
 AlertDialog.Builder builder        = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

 builder.setTitle("Select Image");
 builder.setAdapter( adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int item ) {
 if (item == 0) {
 Intent intent   = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 File file       = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
 "tmp_avatar_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
 mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

 try {  
 intent.putExtra (android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
 mImageCaptureUri);

 intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

 startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
 } catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }          

 dialog.cancel();
 } else {
 Intent intent = new Intent();

 intent.setType("image/*");
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action
 using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
 }
 }
 } );

 final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

 mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test);

 ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_choose)).setOnClickListener(new
 View.OnClickListener() {           
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 dialog.show();
 }
 });
 }

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
 data) {
 if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

 Bitmap bitmap  = null;
 String path        = "";

 if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_FILE) {
 mImageCaptureUri = data.getData(); 
 path = getRealPathFromURI(mImageCaptureUri); //from Gallery 

 if (path == null)
 path = mImageCaptureUri.getPath(); //from File Manager

 if (path != null) 
 bitmap     = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
 } else {
 path   = mImageCaptureUri.getPath();
 bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
 }

 mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 

 mImageView.setSelected(true);

 }

 public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
 String [] proj         = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
 Cursor cursor      = managedQuery( contentUri, proj, null, null,null);

 if (cursor == null) return null;

 int column_index   =
 cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

 cursor.moveToFirst();

 return cursor.getString(column_index);
 }
 }

 Maim.XML

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:padding="10dp">

 <TextView  
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:text="Android Image Choose Example"/>

 <Button 
 android:id="@+id/btn_choose"
 android:text="Choose Image"         
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

 <ImageView 
 android:id="@+id/test"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

 </LinearLayout>


 Any help will be most appreciated, thank you for time and interest.

 Mike
```

Comment: I rolled my own camera app and all the images are stored in the apps image directory. Hope this helps with this answer.

Comment: I think I figured out the logic for this task. What is needed:

Comment: 1.Look in the app image directory for the image, when alarm details are set with a image picker get and set that image to the ImageView container in the target activity or alarm screen. I am still new at this so two questions in my mind arise out of this logic. 1. Do I need more than one instance of the ImageView for each alarm. 2. Use position of image in the directory for ID.                                                                                                  Thanks for any help and interest.  Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all that had interest in this question. After much research trial and error, my logic proved to be correct. Project focus has changed at this point to a new aspect of the application.   Mike